# yii blog comment model with multimodel form

Tags: php, yii

I would like to take the blog comment model and turn the form into a mulitimodel form but I have not been able to work this out. Would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Taken the design below I want to add another table (OtherModel) off of comment with a FK in comment linking the tables.

[image]

Controller

```
public function actionView()
{
    $post=$this->loadModel();
    $comment=$this->newComment($post);

    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$post,
        'comment'=>$comment,
    ));
}

protected function newComment($post)
{
    $comment=new Comment;
    $otherModel=new OtherModel;
    if(isset($_POST['Comment'], $_POST['OtherModel']))
    {
        $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
        $otherModel->attributes=$_POST['OtherModel'];
        if($post->addComment($comment))
        {
            if($comment->status==Comment::STATUS_PENDING)
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted','Thank you...');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    return $comment;
}
```

model

```
public function addComment($comment)
    {
        $comment->other_id=$otherModel->other_id;
        $otherModel->save();
        if(Yii::app()->params['commentNeedApproval'])
            $comment->status=Comment::STATUS_PENDING;
        else
            $comment->status=Comment::STATUS_APPROVED;
        $comment->post_id=$this->id;
        return $comment->save();
    }
```

render form through CJuiTabs

```
'Comment'=>$this->renderPartial('/comment/_form',array($model->$comment=>),true)
```

form

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'comment-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

        <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'author'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'author',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'author'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'content',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'content'); ?>
        </div>

        // added otherModel as part of MMF
        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($otherModel,'name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($otherModel,'name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($otherModel,'name'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($otherModel,'description'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textArea($otherModel,'description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($otherModel,'description'); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="row buttons">
                <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Submit' : 'Save'); ?>
        </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: would you mind to explain in more detail about what you're asking because I do not understand your point about the meaning of 'multimodel'

Comment: @aslingga, Such as [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake in your code given above: you are trying to use `$otherModel` variable instead of `$comment` rendered by your `actionView()` method.

Have you tried to use examples posted on yiiframework.com? I mean the link you've given in comment to your question. If it does not suit you, I afraid I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: sainr, the $otherModel is correct, this is the model that is related to the Comment model.  This is why the problem is unique I want to collect values for both Comment and OtherModel at the same time use the Post controller.

Comment: Ok, the question is more clear for me now. So maybe there were some errors occured during execution?

Comment: And I'm not sure why you use `$otherModel->save();` in `addComment` method where `$otherModel` is look like a local variable.

Comment: sainr, To hopefully let you know what I am after.  Looking at #2 [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/comment.create) I have this set up and working just fine (this is using the Post controller and views to create new Comments).  The goal now is to be able to use that same _form (/wwwroot/blog/protected/views/comment/_form.php) and capture data from 2 models at the same time (i.e. Comment & OtherModel) using that same Post controller & view.  Thank you for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: I am not even to the point of execution yet since when I add the required form input from OtherModel (name & description above) onto the Comment model form the page will not render giving an Error 500.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should validate both models before saving, otherwise you'd end up with a stale $otherModel record in your database.

```
protected function newComment($post)
{
    $comment=new Comment;
    $otherModel=new OtherModel;
    if(isset($_POST['Comment'], $_POST['OtherModel']))
    {
        $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
        $otherModel->attributes=$_POST['OtherModel'];
        // also specify $otherModel as a param
        if($post->addComment($comment, $otherModel))
        {
            if($comment->status==Comment::STATUS_PENDING)
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted','Thank you...');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    return $comment;
}


public function addComment($comment, $otherModel)
{
    // Validate both models, return false if there are errors.
    // Errors should be available via $model->getErrors()
    if ($comment->validate() && $otherModel->validate()) {
        // save the otherModel first to obtain the generated ID
        $otherModel->save();
        $comment->other_id=$otherModel->id;                    
        if(Yii::app()->params['commentNeedApproval'])
            $comment->status=Comment::STATUS_PENDING;
        else
            $comment->status=Comment::STATUS_APPROVED;
        $comment->post_id=$this->id;
        return $comment->save();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: You may also use [transactions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#using-transactions) here.